# Qt + VTK fails to run on Surface Pro X

Tags: windows, qt, opengl-es, vtk

I have an application I have been working on for the past year. It builds and runs normally in various machines (including Mac OS). I just got a Surface Pro X and was surprised I was having issues when rendering in a `QVTKOpenGLWidget`. The application runs, but when I open a window with a `QVTKOpenGLWidget`, it crashes and gives access violation error in Qt5Gui.dll.

I changed from `QVTKOpenGLWidget` to `QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget` which seemed to have improved somewhat the situation, but I can't render anything. The window opens and stays open so long as I don't add any actor or call to render.

From looking at the logs, Qt seems to have issues with creating a context. The VTK logs keep popping up the following error:

> vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow (0CAD3408): GLEW could not be initialized: Missing GL version

I have tried the following with no positive results:

```
// First attempt
auto format = QVTKOpenGLWidget::defaultFormat();
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

// Second attempt
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::defaultFormat());
```

Has anyone figured out how to get this working? I don't think the problem is specific to the Surface Pro X, but to any Windows GPU driver.

Comment: It sounds like an OpenGL driver issue.  I'm not a Windows person, but maybe you need to download an OpenGL driver?

Comment: I just noticed the windows website states that "Games and apps won't work if they use a version of OpenGL greater than 1.1" for the Surface Pro X. Do you think this may be the reason?

Comment: That's possible.  I don't even know if Windows machines come with OpenGL installed by default.  I would suggest asking people over at the VTK discourse (discourse.vtk.org)